# How to get current base urls path of django app

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm making a reusable Django app, let's say its name is Polls. This app is supposed to work properly no matter where it's being configured in the urls.py of its parent app.

Consider the following structure just like that in the Django tutorial

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        urls.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

So, the polls app has its own urls.py and its own views.py which can be linked to any other app, such a mysite by adding a line to **mysite/mysite/urls.py** such as line 5 in this example urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

In this example, all views of the polls app will have a link like **https://somedomain.com/polls/the-relative-page-link** However, the polls app should still function correctly even if we edited line 5 in the above code to other base path such as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('another-path/', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

So that would change the like to **https://somedomain.com/another-path/the-relative-page-link**

My problem is that some of the views of the "polls" app contain custom javascript code that communicate with another view that represents a server-side API. So in order for this communication to work properly regardless of whether polls URLs are under **/polls** or under **/another-path**, I need a way to dynamically find the current path of the polls app so it can generate the correct javascript code that can communicate with its APIs. How do I do this or what's the conventional way of handling such situations when making reusable apps?

Comment: Perhaps render the needed urls somewhere in the HTML (as some hidden element with data attributes or use the [`json_script` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script)) and get those using the id?

Comment: So, basically, I will be getting the path of the client HTML page and use it to calculate the relative API path? But the problem here would be that it's not one page that makes the API requests. There are multiple pages and their locations are dynamic too...

Answer (score 0):

in `polls/urls.py`

```
     from .view import Http404View
     urlpatterns = [
          ...,
          re_path('^$', Http404View, name='mysite_baseurl'),
     ]
```

in `polls/views.py`

```
     def Http404View(request):
         raise Http404()
```

Now you can simply do a `reverse('mysite_baseurl')` to get the base directory you are wanting.

If someone tries to go there directly, they will get the 404 page